# jfrog artifactory 6.0.3 - missing Admin Module - Advanced feature ( To check System Information, etc)

Tags: artifactory

After installing jfrog artifactory 6.0.3 pro (trial license), I did not see Advanced menu list under Admin Module for me to check System Information. May I know how to do enable the Advanced menu list ?

Thanks,
hulkcoder

Comment: Is that on your own install or using an instance hosted on the cloud?

Comment: installed my own. apparently i found out the behavior only happens in Chrome but working ok in FF and IE.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance you're working with zoom in the browser?
I checked it and it seems like when I get to 150% zoom in chrome the advanced section indeed disappear.

If you're working with Internet Explorer we already faced this issue in the past but we fixed this problem in earlier versions. I just checked it now with IE11 and the latest Edge version and it seems OK also with high zoom.

If it's not about the zoom let me know witch browser and what version you're using so I can check it in the same environment.

Comment: Hi, Matan.G. Thank you for replying. 

yes, i think it is related to resolution. I tested on a lower resolution monitor (1280x1024)and I am able to see the Advanced section. 

For your information, my chrome zoom is by default 100%, and my laptop screen resolution is 2560x1440 (also by default). If I reduce to 90%, I am able to see the the Advanced section.

Comment: @hulkcoder Thank you very much for your response - I'll test it and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

@matan-g , I also ran into this.

With Chrome on MacOS zoomed out to 67% zoom, Artifactory 6.x's slide-in-from-the-left Admin menu was clipping out the entire Advanced menu section.  Zooming in a step ( mine indicated going from 67% to 75%) re-materialized the menu->Admin->Advanced section again.

Thank you for the Zoom hint!